# TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsm

What this kind of error?

Traceback error

```
C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyNew\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/MyNew/agaaaaain.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyNew\venv\lib\site- 
packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 530, in EnsureDispatch
    ti = disp._oleobj_.GetTypeInfo()
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, 
None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/MyNew/agaaaaain.py", line 3, in 
<module>
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
 File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyNew\venv\lib\site- 
packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 541, in EnsureDispatch
raise TypeError("This COM object can not automate the makepy process - 
please run makepy manually for this object")
TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run 
makepy manually for this object

Process finished with exit code 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/MyNew/agaaaaain.py", line 3, in 
<module>
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\MyNew\venv\lib\site- 
packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 541, in EnsureDispatch
    raise TypeError("This COM object can not automate the makepy process - 
please run makepy manually for this object")
TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run 
makepy manually for this object
```

and this is my code

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

## I am using `PyCharm` `VirtualEnv`

I didn't find any solution, any one have idea about this?

Note:How ever I am trying to use win32 to access `excel` work book, as to able for modifying it!!..

Comment: I had the same issue lately. Kill EXCEL process in task manager.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must consider running the code from a Virtual Environment.

And uninstall any other pywin32 module outside the Environment.

Give it a shot!

Answer (score 16):

Encountered the same issue and resolve it by closing all running Excel applications.

Answer (score 1):

in case of someone running
`excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')`
with this mistake,
you should check if excel has any notifications, you need to close them and code will run. Can't find any notifications - try to shut down excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...was fixed in my case by adding those 2 lines:

```
workbook.Close(SaveChanges=True)
xl.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue also can arise if running the line `excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')` more then once in your instance (AKA. a `For` loop).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using events over different threads and I forgot setting the `coinit_flags` to zero, for example:

```py
# ...
import sys
sys.coinit_flags = 0  # pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED == 0
from win32com.client import *
from win32com.client.connect import *
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run makepy manually:** Use the PythonWin environment (which should be installed alongside pywin32) to generate the necessary wrappers for the Excel COM object.

**Open PythonWin:**

- PythonWin is an IDE that comes bundled with pywin32. You can find it in the directory where pywin32 is installed, typically something like PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\PythonWin.exe, where XX is your Python version.
  Run PythonWin. You can either navigate to the folder and double-click on PythonWin.exe or launch it from the Start Menu (if it's added there).

**Access the COM MakePy utility:**

- In PythonWin, navigate to the menu bar and choose Tools.
- From the drop-down menu, select COM MakePy utility.

**Locate the Microsoft Excel Library:**

- A dialog box will appear, listing all the registered COM libraries on your system.
- Scroll down to find the library for Microsoft Excel. It will usually be named something like "Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library" where XX.X is the version number (e.g., 16.0 for Excel 2016).

**Generate Python Wrappers:**

- Once you've located and selected the appropriate library for Microsoft Excel, click on OK.
- The utility will generate Python wrappers for the Excel COM object. You'll see the progress in the PythonWin output console.

**After the process completes, Python wrappers for the Excel COM objects are cached, and you should be able to interface with Excel using win32com.client without encountering the "cannot automate makepy" error.**